# Cropped iPad simulator in xCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

For some reason the iPad simulator is cropped like that (50% scale):
[image]
This happens if scale is not 100%. On 100% is ok. If someone know why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. Open the Debug menu and de-select "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale". It affects iOS 8.x and 9.0 Simulators when used with Xcode 8.0.